А кто как работает с дизайном, как дизайнеры устанавливают размеры UI элементов?
В нашей компании мы работаем с Figma, и допустим у нас есть экран в дизайнере который в ширину 1080px так же есть кнопка которая в дизайнере занимает ширину - 200px
но для поддрежки разности экранов используется dp. Отсюда вопрос - кто как работает с дирайнерами? Вы в коде конвертируете px -> dp или сразу высчитываете сколько это dp и используете это значение? Или может дизан базируется на dp а не на px?

Мы используем дизайн в dp, как вот тут описано: For Android mobile design targeting MDPI (Medium Density ~160 DPI), it’s recommended to start with a screen size of 360px by 640px in Figma.
https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/what-is-px-dp-dpi-in-android-decoding-for-designers-8007e7aec4a9

в идеале дизайн должен быть в dp. но был опыт, когда дизайнер рисовал в px, но все разрабы считали, что это dp

@Wlad то есть для примера скажем у вас есть кнопка в дизайне ширина которой 200 px, значит у вас в коде был конвертор типо 200.pxToDpWithOffset чтоб подогнать пиксели под dp или вы просто в ручную пересчитывали сколько это dp и сразу писали (допустим) 100.dp?

@Sirop4ik в том случае 200px были равны 200dp. вообще, по хорошему, вам надо либо дизайнеру люлей давать, либо подгонять +- на глаз. если дизайн в Px нарисован, то скорее всего там и пропорции не соблюдены (или подогнаны под макет, но по разному будет смотреть на разных девайсах). я в фигме не оч разбираюсь, но сейчас есть возможность сразу включить как отображаться данные "css / ios / android" и андроид делится на "xml / compose". зависит ли это от настроект проекта - не знаю. но лучше как-то так сделать.
